# Why is this lambda expression valid for the constructor argument

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I have a constructor of `RelayCommand` set as:

```
public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
```

And in another script I have:

```
    private Server _server;
    public RelayCommand ConnectToServerCommand {get; set;}

    public MainViewModel() // constructor
    {
        _server = new Server();


        //this syntax is confusing to me - not sure what it's doing
        ConnectToServerCommand = new(o => _server.Connect());
    }
```

I don't really understand the syntax for the `ConnectToServerCommand` in the `MainViewModel` constructor.

The `RelayCommand` takes in an Action with an object parameter type, yet the `_server.Connect()` method has this signature:

```
// Server
public void Connect()
```

Why does it allow this method to be used when it does not have an object as one of it's arguments? Given the action is set to `Action<object>`. How is it considering this a valid method signature?

I am still new to this - so I think the lambda expression is confusing me a little but, not sure how they connect together here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Method

> `o => _server.Connect()`

is the same as this Method

```
void Anon(object o) 
{
    // argument o is ignored
    _server.Connect();
}
```

making this code equivalent to yours:

```
private Server _server;
public RelayCommand ConnectToServerCommand {get; set;}

// un-lambda-ed
void Anon(object o) 
{
    _server.Connect();
}

public MainViewModel() // constructor
{
    _server = new Server();

    // no confusion
    ConnectToServerCommand = new(Anon);
}
```

Let's have both calls in the constructor:

```
public MainViewModel() // constructor
{
    _server = new Server();

    ConnectToServerCommand = new(o => _server.Connect());
    // no confusion
    ConnectToServerCommand = new(Anon);
}
```

and then compare the generated Intermediate Language:

```
MainViewModel:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  newobj      UserQuery+Server..ctor
IL_0006:  stfld       UserQuery._server              // _server = new Server();
IL_000B:  ldarg.0     
IL_000C:  ldarg.0     
IL_000D:  ldftn       UserQuery.<MainViewModel>b__0  // our lamda function, see below
IL_0013:  newobj      System.Action<System.Object>..ctor
IL_0018:  newobj      UserQuery+RelayCommand..ctor
IL_001D:  call        UserQuery.set_ConnectToServerCommand
IL_0022:  ldarg.0     
IL_0023:  ldarg.0     
IL_0024:  ldftn       UserQuery.Anon                 // our Anon call
IL_002A:  newobj      System.Action<System.Object>..ctor
IL_002F:  newobj      UserQuery+RelayCommand..ctor
IL_0034:  call        UserQuery.set_ConnectToServerCommand
IL_0039:  ret         

<MainViewModel>b__0:  // generated by the compiler for us, the lambda
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     // object o, nothing gets done with that
IL_0001:  ldfld       UserQuery._server
IL_0006:  callvirt    UserQuery+Server.Connect
IL_000B:  ret         

Anon:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     // object o, nothing gets done with that
IL_0001:  ldfld       UserQuery._server
IL_0006:  callvirt    UserQuery+Server.Connect
IL_000B:  ret
```

That is remarkable similar.

Answer (score 2):

Your lambda defines a function/method hat accepts an object `o`, and just ignores it. That’s fine, the signature says you have to accept one, not that it has to be useful.

```
public int Something(object o)
{
    return 12;
}
```

is a fine, though inefficient (because it takes an unnecessary parameter) function.